# How to link a manager with the manager's team and supervisor?

Tags: 7, users, webforms, workflows

A user submits a webform, the user's manager can validate it to him/her or not. After validation the manager sends the webform to another department for validation.

I'm using [Webform Workflow](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_workflow) for changing the status of the webform. Now I don't know what options I have so that when the manager submits his/her own webform, the webform is sent to the manager's director.

I tried the [Subuser](https://www.drupal.org/project/subuser) module but it's not what I'm looking for, it doesn't work for me: I need to link for each manager the manager's team of simple users and the supervisor of the manager.

Any suggestions?